# pdf images position and scaling

Tags: image, pdf, scaling

I have some images in a pdf document, they are singular images saved in the pdf, but then are rebuilt together. I have to rebuild the entire image, but I don't understand something...so, the extract in the pdf is:

```
Q
q
cm:36.442 0 0 88.32 71.94 462.56 
Do:/Im1
Q
q
cm:54.92 0 0 88.32 106.962 462.56 
Do:/Im5
Q
q 
cm:20.018 0 0 88.32 160.342 462.56 
Do:/Im10
```

Im1 is 71x206 pixels, Im2 is 107x206 and Im3 is 39x706.

I don't understand how to apply the x scale factor to the single images, it seems they are xscaled, but if I calculate they don't appears one beside the other, as it should be.
 In addition, if, knowing nothing of pdf, I merge these images all together, the union image results not aligned. Anyone could explain me better? Thank you

Comment: The excerpt you show (which is not in PDF syntax as **cm** and **Do** are post fix operations) mentions **Im1**, **Im5**, and **Im10**. Later you talk about **Im1**, **Im2**, and **Im3**. Have you probably looked at the wrong images? Furthermore, without the images (or at least a precise description how much they overlap where at which scale) it is difficult to help.

Comment: Sorry, Im1, Im2 and Im3 are, respectively, Im1, Im5 and Im10. These images are png, I'm able to rebuild them on files. If you think it should be better, I can attach also these files. It seems to me that here cm it's for positioning and scaling images, are there other informations that have to be looked for in the pdf to merge this images together?

Comment: Yes, the **cm** operations are what you need. You also have to decide the height (in pixel) of the result image. The source image have different heights (206, 206, and 706), so there is no single canonical choice.